# Не получается пищать PC спикером из python

Tags: python, linux, железо

Пытаюсь пищать в linux из скрипта Pyton. Сразу оговорюсь - системная утилита beep отлично пищит - т.е. спикер живой, система о нём знает.
делаю по образу и подобию исходника beep.c из пакета busybox но уже на питоне:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import fcntl
import time

KIOCSOUND = 0x4B2F
CLOCK_TICK_RATE = 1193180

def beep(hz, len):
    fd = os.open("/dev/console", os.O_WRONLY)
    try:
        fcntl.ioctl(fd, KIOCSOUND, int(CLOCK_TICK_RATE / hz))
        try:
            time.sleep(len)
        finally:
            fcntl.ioctl(fd, KIOCSOUND, 0)
    finally:
        os.close(fd)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    beep(440, 0.5)
```

и получаю ошибку:

```
fcntl.ioctl(fd, KIOCSOUND, int(CLOCK_TICK_RATE/hz))
OSError: [Errno 25] Not a tty
```

пока вывернулся - запуская процесс beep. Но это как-то не красиво. Что я делаю не так в питоне?

Comment: скорей всего у тебя `open()` проваливается: обычно `/dev/console` доступен только root'у...

Comment: нет. он возвращает 6ой fd, ну как минимум не ошибку. Ну и запускаю я от root.

Comment: А если попробовать открывать прямо вот `/dev/tty`?

Comment: гмм... тогда хз... УМВР... я бы `strace`'ом посмотрел, что именно `beep` из busybox'а делает, раз он работает...

Comment: Дык что там смотреть, он в открытом коде...

Comment: `-ENOTTY` еяпп возвращается на неверный IOCTL. То есть драйвер `/dev/console` не предоставляет таковой.

Comment: Вот, если хотите видеть, откуда это: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/ioctl.c#L843

Comment: Всё понятно, у вас номер для команды неправильный. Вам надо составить число с помощью `_IOC()` или разобраться с Питоном, что он там хочет видеть.

Comment: @CrazyElf: по факту это он и есть. Пробовал явно открывать и /dev/tty - fd всё равно 6ой, и всё равно ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге всё получилось и заработало. Дело было действительно в `/dev/console`, а точнее в `/dev/tty0`. Как посоветовал @Fat-Zer глянул, что делает beep и обнаружил, что он после не удачной попытки с `/dev/tty` начинает перебирать по маске `/dev/tty*` и первый же отлично пищит.
У меня решение под конкретную железку, поэтому пока жёсткое указание `/dev/tty0` решило проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрим файл *errno-base.h* :

```
#define ENOTTY          25      /* Not a typewriter */
```

Т.е. 25-я ошибка - это ENOTTY. Смотрим *man ioctl* - что это за ошибка:

> ENOTTY Указанный запрос не применяется к типу объекта, на который
> ссылается файловый дескриптор fd.

Это означает, что Ваша ioctl команда *KIOCSOUND = 0x4B2F* - не применима к данному устройству. Или Вы придумали эту команду, или данная реализация драйвера её не поддерживает.

Comment: Ну не придумал - оно есть в мануале и хидерах. beep с ней отлично уживается и пищит. Значит драйвер поддерживает и работает.